# Notebook cannot boot Windows 10 from SSD, fix using USB bootloader?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bootloader, bootable-media

I have a Samsung Q320 notebook (Phoenix Bios, build date 2010) where I replaced the 320GB HDD with a SanDisk SSD Plus 250GB flashdrive. Using the Windows 10 DVD boot, I can choose the partition, but get the warning that installation cannot continue because the system could not boot it.

Inside the BIOS, the SSD is listed in the overview startpage but in the boot order section, it cannot be selected. Even after I installed Windows10 on the SSD from another PC and the boot sector and partitioning exists properly (the other PC boots from it).

Now to fix this, is there a way to create a USB stick that simply boots into the SSD Windows 10 installation somehow?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to disable secure boot and cold boot (fast boot) and trying the uefi boot settings, if that doesn't work, you can install grub bootloader to the USB stick.

Comment: Secure boot is disabled already, I also disabled cold boot, also tried with legacy bios option, all without success. How do I install a grub bootloader to an USB stick for Windows 10, do you happen to have a link/howto for that scenario?

Comment: have you tried enabling uefi booting(if available)? also try installing grub on the usb stick, with only the option to boot to the ssd.